# Early binding for static method which was invoked in a non static method

Tags: java

Precondition:A static method in the super class was invoked by a non static method in the same class, and that non static method was invoked by a object of one sub class.

My question is:

1.Compile-time: The subClassObject(now it is treated as SuperClass type) was bound to staticMethod()?

2.Run-time:The subClassObject(now it is treated as a object of subClass.) was bound to nonStaticMethod()?

```
package a;

public class SuperClass {

    public static void staticMethod() {
        System.out.println("Superclass.");
    }

    public void nonStaticMethod() {
        staticMethod();
    }
}
```

```
package a;

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {

    public static void staticMethod() {
        System.out.println("Subclass.");
    }
}
```

```
package a;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SubClass subClassObject = new SubClass();
        subClassObject.nonStaticMethod(); // output: Superclass;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: And there goes another one of the beloved Do-My-Homework questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static methods are bound to the class - they can not be overridden. The non static method calls the static method of its class, implicitly specifying `SuperClass.staticMethod()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I feel ashamed of my poor English.But the question still puzzled me.Compile-time: The subClassObject(now it is treated as SuperClass type) was bound to staticMethod()?Run-time:The subClassObject(now it is treated as a object of subClass.) was bound to nonStaticMethod()?

Comment: @john instance (non static) methods can be overridden - this is the essence of OOP: subclasses specifiy their custom implementation for (often abstract) behaviour of the super class. Binding to instance methods is (necessarily) done at runtime. However, static methods, not being overridable, are bound at compile time based on the context of the call - either the variable type, or the class the method is called from if not qualified. Think of it this way: because static methods can't be overridden, the super class can't "see" the subclass's static methods, so it won't call them.